# How to free a Pascal function's TStringList?

Tags: object, pascal, free, freepascal, lazarus

I've got a function in Pascal which returns a `StringList` as the result. How do I free it correctly? As it's not a global variable I can't free it in the `Form.FormDestroy` procedure. And freeing it after returning it doesn't work either (that should be allowed though, LOL).

In general, is there a way to free all objects (including the ones that the form has no control over) as soon as the program is closed?

Comment: Destroy it once you have finished using it. How to do that depends on which object owns it and determines its lifetime. Lots of possible patterns. We can't tell you which one to use without more information. Better that you read a good book to learn the concepts.

Comment: I don't need it anymore as soon as the function's result is returned. But I don't see a real option of freeing the StringList because that obviously cannot happen before the result and after it doesn't work either. As it's a local variable I cannot access it from anywhere outside of the function.

Comment: So destroy it when the function returns.

Comment: Take a reference to the returned `TStringList` and use that ref to free it: `var sl: TStringList; begin sl := ReturnAStringList; UseTheList; sl.Free; end;`

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks, that makes sense! I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TomBrunberg is right, his comment solved the problem:

Take a reference to the returned `TStringList` and use that ref to free it:

```
var 
  sl: TStringList; 
begin
  sl := fnThatReturnsAStringList; 
  UseTheList(sl);
  sl.Free; 
end;
```

Another possibility, in case you call the function only because of side effects of that call, *without any interest in the returned `TStringList`*, you may even free it simply by calling:

```
begin
  fnThatReturnsAStringList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I added another possibility as you also said in a comment: *I don't need it anymore as soon as the function's result is returned.*

Comment: In the 1st example, you should wrap the `Free` in a `try..finally` block, in case `UseTheList()` raises an exception: `sl := fnThatReturnsAStringList; try UseTheList(sl); finally sl.Free; end;`